# Closed symplectic manifold with Euler characteristic 2

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology

I am working about an article. In this article, author said that if close symplectic manifold $M$ has two fixed points implies that either $M$ is 2-sphere or $\dim M=6$.
The closed symplectic manifold $M$ has two fixed points means that the Euler characteristic of $M$ is $2$ but I don't know why $M$ should be 2-sphere or $\dim M=6$.

Is there any closed symplectic manifold with Euler characteristic $2$?

Comment: You say If a manifold has two fixed points... for what kind of group action?

Comment: Action is Semifree circle action

Comment: Is it assumed to be Hamiltonian or symplectic? (If it is Hamiltonian and the fixed point set has two elements then $M$ must be a $2$-sphere, this follows from the localisation of Betti numbers formula)

Comment: As far as I understand, it is only symplectic circle action. Author's sentence is that "If a symplectic circle action on a closed symplectic manifold $M$ has two fixed points, then either $M$ is the 2-sphere or $dimM=6$ and the weights at the two fixed points are ${-a-b,a,b}$ and ${-a,-b,a+b}$ for some positive integers $a$ and $b$."

Comment: I see. Regarding the last part of the question, without the assumption of a group action there are plenty of symplectic manifolds with Euler characteristic $2$. For example if we blow up $\mathbb{CP}^{3}$ in a smooth genus $2$ curve.

Comment: Is this the article you're looking at? https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.4169 In the future you may want to cite it explicitly and link it in your post as including such information gives more context to the question.